# What is the number of cycles needed to execute the following loop?

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu, computer-science, pipeline, cpu-architecture

> Consider a 4 stage pipeline processor. The number of cycles needed by
>    the four instructions I1, I2, I3, I4 in stages S1, S2, S3, S4 is shown below:

```
    S1    S2    S3    S4
I1  2     1     1     1
I2  1     3     2     2
I3  2     1     1     3
I4  1     2     2     2
```

> What is the number of cycles needed to execute the following loop?

```
For (i=1 to 2) {I1; I2; I3; I4;}
```

Options are:

1. 16
2. 23
3. 28
4. 30

---

**My explanation :**

---

[image]

where I'm wrong ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the following timeline I get **23** cycles:

[image]

Comment: why you are using 1 clock cycle for intn 4 on first iteration and 2 clock cycle on second iteration at stage S3?

Comment: @m.s.: Your answer is complete for this question. Is there a general way to find the number of cycles needed for a given instruction set?

Comment: @displayName I guess you need some kind of "simulator" to find out the number of cycles for a set of instructions; this can be a simple spreadsheet as used above or a full blown processor simulator.

Comment: @m.s.: My thought was that if we had some way to not only show that 23 cycles is the best time _you_ are getting, but also prove that it can't be done better than this, it'd be icing on the cake.

Comment: @displayName this is not my area of expertise, but if I were to **prove** something like this, I'd first try to model the processor as a petri net or a finite state machine; you could ask this question at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where did I3 go at time slot 6? The S1 was occupied by I4 and I2 had not left S2?

Answer (score 0):

answer should be 23 cycles...
You are wrong from timeline 10 onwards
[image]